# How does this C# function composition method work?

Tags: c#, .net, functional-programming, func

I've occured the following code:

```
public static class FuncUtils
{
    public static Func<T1, T3> Compose<T1, T2, T3> (Func<T1, T2> f1, Func<T2, T3> f2)
    {
        return a => f2(f1(a));
    }
}
```

What's the biggest mystery for me is this one

> return a => f2(f1(a));

Can you explain how does it work?

Comment: It returns a function that takes a and returns f2(f1(a)).

Comment: This returns a new function which receives an argument `a` and whose body is `f2(f1(a))`. When that function is called it will call `f1` on a and then `f2` on that result. That's why the method is called `Compose`. It takes two functions `f1, f2` and returns a third that calls `f1` on the results of `f2`

Comment: That is a *lambda* expression.

Comment: I'd say someone is trying to replicate the ` >> ` operator in F# which allows you to write `(f1 >> f2)(a)`

Comment: Example: let's say you have a `Func<int, int> add5 = i => i + 5;` and a `Func<int, int> doubleIt = i => i * 2;` Then `FuncUtils.Compose(add5, doubleIt)` will give you a function `f` that adds 5 and then multiplies by 2, so `f(3) = 16`

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition_(computer_science)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will return a `Func<T1, T3>`, **that is a function (delegate) that takes some parameter of type `T1` and returns a result of type `T3`** . Let's call the returned `Func` `f`

The result (returned value) of `f` is just the result from the **2 function parameters `f1` and `f2` composed** (as in math function composition) on any parameter given.

More on `f`, the returned `Func`:

Apply `f1` on the parameter `a` (of type `T1`), get some result `b` (of type `T2`), then apply `f2` on `b` , call this result `c` (of type `T3`). `c` will be the result for any `a` passed to `f` .

Answer (score 2):

You need to understand the concept of higher order functions to make sense of the above method. Higher order functions are modeled as *delegates* in .NET and therefore in c#. A delegate is a data type that represents a method to be called. So you when you execute your method, the result you get is another method that you need to call to get your result (hence *higher order* function).

So let's dissect your method:

The parameters `Func<T1, T2> f1` and `Func<T2, T3> f2` are delegates, which each represent a method. You can call these methods by calling the delegates:

```
//You need a value of type T1, here represented by the variable a
T2 value = f1(a);
```

The call must look like this, because this is how the delegate id defined:

```
public delegate TResult Func<T, TResult>(T item);
```

You can call `f2` like you call `f1`, just with a different parameter type. Since `T2` is the return of `f1` and the parameter of `T2`, you can just pass the result of `f1` to `f2`:

```
T2 result = f2(value);
```

Or inline:

```
T2 result = f2(f1(a));
```

You will find this in your method, which means it performs a nested call of the two methods.

In a special twist, `Compose` does not call the methods and return the result, it returns a higher order function by itself. It uses the lambda operator `=>` for this, which is another way to create a delegate. To the left of the lambda operator is `a`, which is an arbitrary name for the new function's parameter. The type of `a` is `T1`, which the compiler can figure out by *type inferrence*.

So in the end the caller has to execute the returned delegate to get the final result. This is called *defered execution* and is commonplace in LINQ.

You can think of thw `Compose` method of a way to nest the call to two methods before you actually make the call.